# Schema method property usage

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, model

In my userSchema I have method

```
userSchema.method({
  fields: ['id', 'name', 'email', 'createdAt'],
  transform: function () {
    const fields = ['id', 'name', 'email', 'createdAt']

    const transformed = {}

    fields.forEach((field) => {
      transformed[field] = this[field]
    })

    return transformed
  },
```

It's working fine but when I remove `const fields` and use this keyword, like this:

```
userSchema.method({
  fields: ['id', 'name', 'email', 'createdAt'],
  transform: function () {

    const transformed = {}

    this.fields.forEach((field) => {
      transformed[field] = this[field]
    })

    return transformed
  },
```

then I have some weird issue in response:

> "message": "schema.methods[method][k].bind is not a function",

What does it mean? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: As far as I know, `this` refers to the document's model, no to the `fields` property you've declare before in the `method` object. So, if your document doesn't have a property called `fields` which contains an iterable, what you are attempting will fail.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NZyyrb?editors=0010

Comment: this is working just fine. does mongoose somehow change this to something else?

Comment: Happens you are passing an array as a method, and Mongoose is especting for a function instead.

Comment: Omg but I need this transform function in external file with parameter because I'm using it in many models

Comment: I don't want to repeat this function everywhere

Comment: Remember that [`methods`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods) are instance related to the document it belongs to. I really don't get what you are trying to do here exactly. When you say that do not want to repeat this function everywhere, I really think that for each model, you've got to do exactly that. One way to do the trick is declaring a field called `fields` in the document model, which contains the `array` you are declaring in the `methods` object.